# zooming animation is not smooth in Premiere CS6

Tags: video, premiere, effects, post-production

Animatedly, I tried to zoom into a video clip in Premiere by creating two Position keyframes and two Scale keyframes

[image: Premier transform effect animation]

But [the result is very shaky for some reason?](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3qwy01xxksy1tm/hammering-removal.flv)

What am I doing wrong with this implementation, or should I achieve this zooming effect by other means?

#### Same shaky result using linear interpolations

If I use just Position keyframes (Scale keyframes deleted for troubleshooting), and if I set the keyframes' **Temporal Interpolation** to **Linear** and also the **Spatial Interpolation** to **Linear**, [the resultant video is still jerky, as evidenced here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/me0kvm6fqb3upgd/position-only-linear-animation.flv)

- I set the temporal and spatial interpolations to Linear for both keyframes i.e. for both the starting and middle keyframes

[image: Premier transform effect linear animation]

There are a number of other interpolation options, maybe one of them would help?

Comment: For one think, you are not using linear curves which is going to produce an acceleration and deceleration look. You also may need to render out the output as the preview may not be rendering smoothly. Have you verified if the problem appears on an actual export or is only when you are doing playback within Premiere?

Comment: Does this only occur when you use the zoom and position keyframes? Try keyframing only the position and only the zoom to see if it occurs in those situations too.

Comment: @BartArondson Thanks for the idea, I uploaded [a position-only animation here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/85hwyojnua7a6ub/position-only-animation.flv) and [a scale-only animation here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0af2txfbzyxk1t/scale-only-animation.flv), but both are still jerky? :(

Comment: Thanks AJ, the links to the exported videos demonstrate that the issue occurs outside Premiere as well. I tried linear interpolations as well now, but it did not help - please see the edited question.

Comment: An observation - I think it is smooth inside Premiere, but becomes jerky on export?! At least when I play with half-resolution in Premiere, it seems smooth, but not when I play with full resolution, but that may be a CPU processing bottleneck or what not. I tried different output formats now as well, but they have all been jerky still, although QuickTime export seemed the least shaky. Any ideas?

Comment: @Cel - what is the format of the original video?  I know there are a lot of problems with this particular video clip from the multiple postings about it.  It almost seems like something may be wrong with the source file as there are really bizarre sounds, the video quality is poor and in general, things just seem off about the source clip.  If you export the video with no animation at all, does it still get jumpy?  It may actually be the source video that has the problem and it just doesn't become really obvious until run through an exporter.

Comment: @AJHenderson good idea about disabling effects, but clean output was fine..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that one should use [the Motion effect](http://crawfordschools.org/dshepard/Broadcast%20Video/PSA/p4_09_howto_motion_effect.pdf) and not the Transform effect for zooming in Premiere, even though they have exactly the same Position and Scale controls!

**[Here is the result with the Motion effect](https://www.dropbox.com/s/64lc85thyb6jm3k/zooming-with-motion-effect.flv)**

p.s. [The Anti-Flicker filter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/premierepro/cs/using/WS52DEF9DC-C740-41f3-865A-46DB6827BCC0.html) I discovered under the Motion effect was left to the default of 0, so that was not needed.

p.p.s. I also found [this discussion](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/303107-Premiere-CS4-My-zoom-PNG-image-is-stutter!) of a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**: Increase the Shutter Angle

I came across this (or similar problem) as I was using Transform on an adjustment layer to scale and alter the position of footage. One of the benefits of the Transform effect over the Motion effect is that it seems to scale text better - due to the Sampling option I imagine.

However I was getting really jerky results. I discovered increasing the Shutter Angle solved this. I used a value of 90 but lower might be fine as well depending on the speed of the transform you are performing.